# How to convert this object data into array?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, customer-attribute, array, object

I have this Data Object value.

```
Magento\Customer\Model\Data\AttributeMetadata Object
(
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [frontend_input] => boolean
            [input_filter] => 
            [store_label] => Verified Buyer
            [validation_rules] => Array
                (
                )

            [multiline_count] => 0
            [visible] => 1
            [required] => 
            [data_model] => 
            [options] => Array
                (
                )

            [frontend_class] => 
            [user_defined] => 1
            [sort_order] => 90
            [frontend_label] => Verified Buyer
            [note] => 
            [system] => 
            [backend_type] => int
            [is_used_in_grid] => 
            [is_visible_in_grid] => 
            [is_filterable_in_grid] => 
            [is_searchable_in_grid] => 
            [attribute_code] => verified_buyer
        )

)
```

**I converted this to**

> $array =  (array) $customAttr;

**But still I am reciving the object**

```
Array
(
    [*_data] => Array
        (
            [frontend_input] => boolean
            [input_filter] => 
            [store_label] => Verified Buyer
            [validation_rules] => Array
                (
                )

            [multiline_count] => 0
            [visible] => 1
            [required] => 
            [data_model] => 
            [options] => Array
                (
                )

            [frontend_class] => 
            [user_defined] => 1
            [sort_order] => 90
            [frontend_label] => Verified Buyer
            [note] => 
            [system] => 
            [backend_type] => int
            [is_used_in_grid] => 
            [is_visible_in_grid] => 
            [is_filterable_in_grid] => 
            [is_searchable_in_grid] => 
            [attribute_code] => verified_buyer
        )

)
```

I am expecting output like

```
Array
(
            [frontend_input] => boolean
            [input_filter] => 
            [store_label] => Verified Buyer
            [validation_rules] => Array
                (
                )

            [multiline_count] => 0
            [visible] => 1
            [required] => 
            [data_model] => 
            [options] => Array
                (
                )

            [frontend_class] => 
            [user_defined] => 1
            [sort_order] => 90
            [frontend_label] => Verified Buyer
            [note] => 
            [system] => 
            [backend_type] => int
            [is_used_in_grid] => 
            [is_visible_in_grid] => 
            [is_filterable_in_grid] => 
            [is_searchable_in_grid] => 
            [attribute_code] => verified_buyer
)
```

Above all is Magento Customer custom attributes data.

> Note : I am using REST API

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method toArray().

```
\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer;
$customer->toArray();
```

Comment: Nope, Not working.

Comment: Have an error log?

Comment: Thanks for the efforts +1

Answer (score 1):

The simple way you can do it via php function `json_encode` and `json_decode`.

```
$object = 'your_object_variable'
$myArray = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
print_r($myarray);
```

Comment: Does it works ?

Comment: No, it doesn't.. But thanks for the efforts +1

Answer (score 1):

Try like this one:

```
$data = $this->dataObjectConverter->toFlatArray($Customer, [], \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::class);
```